# How to add an Expires response header to a WebAPI Action response?

Tags: caching, http-headers, asp.net-web-api

I'm pretty sure that "Expires" is valid HTTP Response Header type. But when I try to set it in my code: (this is in an ActionFilter.OnActionExecuted method)

```
actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", (DateTime.Now + Timespan.FromDays(7)).ToString("R"));
```

I end up with an exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Misused header name. Make sure request
>   headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with
>   HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Expires is a content header. Try this instead:

```cs
actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(7);
```

Comment: What is an HTTP Content header?? I've never seen it before, and it looks the same as all the other headers in my server response....

Comment: It is the same. But it's just a header that relates to the content body. So the Content controls those headers.

Comment: @YoussefMoussaoui I get `Expires: -1` back when I try this.

Comment: This is sure to be a naive question, but where does actionExecutedContext come from? I'm in a controller action that returns an IActionResult. I can see a ControllerContext that I get from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase. Where is actionExecutedContext?

Comment: hi @bbsimonbb, you can implement `ActionFilterAttribute` to create a filter that has access to the actionExecutedContext and apply that attribute to controllers or actions you'd like that filter to apply to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/hh835300(v=vs.118)

Comment: @YoussefMoussaoui, Did you get it working. When I tried its returning Expires: -1 along with pragma:no-cache

Comment: I was getting Expires: -1 until I also set Cache-Control: public. I think you need to ensure that there is a compatible cache-control header along with the expires header.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
response.Content.Headers.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(7);
```