# How to get RequestCachePolicy to respect max-age

Tags: .net, caching, httpwebrequest, webrequest, cache-control

I am confused about how [time-based cache policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/time-based-cache-policies) work when using `HttpWebRequest`.

I am calling a GET method of a WebAPI that returns JSON content together with a Cache-Control header similar to:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
```

The intention is that the content should be considered to be stale after `max-age` seconds.

I am calling this API using `HttpWebRequest`, and want subsequent requests to be served from the local cache for `max-age` seconds, then to be retrieved from the server when the content expires.

I've tried different combinations with the results listed below.

1. Do not specify a `RequestCachePolicy`.  In this case, as expected, all requests go to the server.
2. Specify a [default cache policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-set-the-default-time-based-cache-policy-for-an-application):

   ```
   var policy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.Default);
   HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = policy;
   ```

   In this case, all requests still go to the server.  I was expecting requests to be served from the cache for the next `max-age` seconds.
3. Specify a cache policy `CacheIfAvailable`:

   ```
   var policy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.CacheIfAvailable);
   HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = policy;
   ```

   In this case, all requests are served from the local cache, even if the content is stale (i.e. max-age seconds has passed).

Is it possible to achieve what I want, and if so, how?

Comment: I think this might do the job:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cache.httpcacheagecontrol?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ofirule - thanks for the reply.  I've experimented with various combinations of this enum without success.  This appears to allow the client to specify values for MaxAge/MaxStale/MinFresh.  What I want to do is to respect the MaxAge provided by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's necessary for the server to [add an Expires header to the response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15257007/13087), in addition to (or instead of?) the Cache-Control header.  The poster of that answer deserves the bounty.

When an Expires header is present, and RequestCacheLevel.Default is used, expiry behaves as expected in a .NET Framework application: the request is served from the local cache until the expiry time is reached.

However in a .NET Core application, using the same code, all requests are sent to the server and the local cache isn't used :(  This is separate to the subject of my original question so I've [asked a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55856082/13087).